# How can I determine which original source code was a lambda anonymous type?

Tags: java, debugging, lambda, stack-trace, anonymous-types

Consider a stack trace (from [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html), in this case) like the following:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbb18027800 nid=0x5286 in 
Object.wait() [0x00007fbb1e75d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x0000000090ce2d28> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at io.vavr.concurrent.FutureImpl$$Lambda$82/1994084103.run(Unknown Source)
        at io.vavr.control.Try.run(Try.java:105)
        at io.vavr.concurrent.FutureImpl.await(FutureImpl.java:114)
```

One of the objects is a lambda. However, the class [`FutureImpl`](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/master/vavr/src/main/java/io/vavr/concurrent/FutureImpl.java) has many lambdas.

How can I determine which lambda corresponds to which index of the lambda anonymous type? There are 6 lambdas in that class, and that doesn't include the interface it's implementing (which has many default methods).

Answer (score 0):

I'd decompile the class FutureImpl$$Lambda$82 using javap and see what lambda it corresponds to.